# PowerBuilder DataWindow using insert when update is needed

Tags: powerbuilder

The issue I'm having is: I have a DataWindow that on window open checks to see if any rows exist and if not, I manually insert a row. At some point, a row is being inserted into the table before I call update on the DataWindow. When I call update, a row already exists and my updates cannot be saved because it is using insert instead of update. Is there a way to alleviate this?

```
dw_dates.SetTransObject(SQLCA);
dw_dates.Retrieve(gs_facility_pfi, is_pcn);    

if(dw_dates.rowcount() = 0) then
    int row;
    row = dw_dates.InsertRow(1);    
    dw_dates.setitem(row, 'patient_ctrl_num', is_pcn);
    dw_dates.setitem(row, 'pfi_num', gs_facility_pfi);  
end if
```

Comment: Terry is right on with ItemStatus (get/set). But I notice something odd about your code. You break out if dw_dates has no rows but then try inserting a row after row one. I forget how PB handles using a number higher than row count but I'd change it to InsertRow(0) if there are no rows. As Terry mention, if there is some reason itemstatus is wrong you can manipulate it with SetItemStatus but make sure to look at the table on which statuses can be changed to which, a few take two actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerBuilder isn't going to know automagically whether or not there is a row there with the same key. The DataWindow generates INSERT or UPDATE statements based on the row status (see GetItemStatus() in help for details).

It's not really clear what your requirement is. If you want to either insert a new record or overwrite the existing record, I'd suggest a stored procedure update from the DataWindow that determines if whether the INSERT or UPDATE is required and acts accordingly. If you want this client to always INSERT a new record, and adjust the primary key values appropriately so you won't overwrite or conflict with existing data, I'd suggest look to see whether your DBMS supports identity or sequence values for your key column, and look at the Identity Column feature on the DataWindow's Update Properties dialog.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer a business question first.  Do you want to lose the other person's update?

If you are getting the DW msg: Rows changed between Retrieve and Update... that is a valid msg.  If you look in your datawindow, you'll notice by default the columns used by the Update are all of the editable columns.  You can change that to just the primary key.  This would allow your update to "work", but it will also overwrite the other person's changes.

It sounds like your PK is too generic.  You might want to look at a unique, sequence driven approach.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if one would be using "`row = dw_dates.InsertRow(1);`    ", if you want a dummy row then try using     `row = dw_dates.InsertRow(0);`    This would insert the row at the end. Also you may want to use the SetRow or ScrolltoRow in-order to make it the current row.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is that some other user has inserted the row.
Then you must do another check just before you call update() on datawindow.
The best solution is to use stored procedure update and to check there if row exists and decide if you will do INSERT or UPDATE. But then again, if you do UPDATE you will overwrite someone else's data.